# Solving optimzation problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I would like to solve to find the vector Y, solution of this maximization problem

Max Y'C + Y'Br + αr0

Subject two constraints: k=sqrt(Y'ΣY) and Y'e + α = 1

Where Y, C and B are columns vector of n lines.

Σ is symetric matrix of n order

e =(1,....1)' and α is a reel parameter.

r and r0 are reel scalars

C, B, r, r0 are knowns.

I did calculus with lagrangian but i fear that i did some error.
So if someone can help me to solve this fo Y and α.

Comment: It is really difficult to understand your question. Please re-edit it using a cleaner formulation.

Comment: PleaseuseMathJax,itisreallyhardtounderstandyourquestion.

Comment: Why put on hold? The problem is clear to me. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

k=sqrt(Y'ΣY) is a non-convex, and therefore difficult to deal with constraint. It also deviates from the standard formulation, which is to limit portfolio standard deviation, not force it to equal a fixed value. Therefore, I will presume the constraint actually is $\sqrt{Y'ΣY} \le k$, which is equivalent to $Y'ΣY \le k^2$  In reality, as long as the input data are such that positive return can be achieved,  the optimal $Y$ will satisfy this constraint with equality, unless that is not feasible (possible), in which case the equality constrained version would not have a solution, whereas the inequality constrained version still would.

With this modification, this is a convex Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Programming problem (QCQP), which is really a Quadratically Constrained Linear Programming problem. A convex optimization system, such as CVX, will convert this to a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP) and call a solver to solve it.  The term `ar0` in the objective function doesn;t affect the optimal Y, so I will dispense with it, but it can be included if you want.

Here is the CVX formulation:

```
cvx_begin
variable Y(n)
maximize(Y'*(C+B*r))
Y'*Sigma*Y <= k^2
sum(Y) + alpha == 1
cvx_end
```

CVX will call the solver and report the result.

Instead of `Y'*Sigma*Y <= k^2`, this constraint can be specified directly as a second order cone constraint as `norm(R*Y) <= k`, where $R$ is the upper triangular Cholesky factor of $\Sigma$, such that $R^TR = \Sigma$, which is what CVX would do under the hood anyway. This presumes $\Sigma$ is positive definite.  In any event, presumably $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite, being a covariance matrix.

Comment: Σ is cov matrix. There is a program to solve this problem with matlab?

Comment: @oussama tilfani Yes. Download CVX http://cvxr.com/cvx/download/  which is free ands works under MATLAB.  My program should work once you install CVX and enter the input data vectors and matrices into MATLAB.

Comment: thank you for your precious help

Comment: @oussama tilfani Have you tried implementing this?

Comment: L.Stone, not yet do you have other suggestions?

Comment: That's the easiest suggestion for you to implement, presuming that you already use MATLAB.

Comment: Yes i use matlab.

Comment: @oussama tilfani Go ahead and download and install CVX - that should only take a dew minutes. Then you can try running the program in my answer. If you are interested in CVX, then go ahead and read the CVX USer's Guide.

Comment: @ Mark L.Stone i get this error message Warning: A non-empty cvx problem already exists in this scope.
   It is being overwritten. 
> In cvxprob (line 28)
  In cvx_begin (line 41) 
Error using alpha
Too many output arguments.

Comment: @ Mark L. Stone Y elements should be less than one (in absolute values), without alpha in the program i have a solution, but with some Y elements greater than one, which is not acceptable

Comment: You can add the constraint abs(Y)<=1. I don't know what value you used for alpha. Anyhow, a better forum for getting help debugging your CVX program is http://ask.cvxr.com/latest . If you post there, please provide a reproducible problem, with all input data, starting from a fresh MATLAB session. And please read the CVX Users' Guide first.